# Setup bitcoin-seeder

Tags: cryptography, domain-registering

I wanna setup a dnsseed for a crypto currency using [sipa/bitcoin-seeder](https://github.com/sipa/bitcoin-seeder) on my VPS.
The server is hosted at NetCup and running the software as root, and also listening on port :53 UDP.

My domain is hosted at GoDaddy and got those records:

```
dnsseed.machinenode.de  1800     IN     NS  ns01.machinenode.de.
ns01    1800     IN     A   SERVER_IP
```

However, if I use `dig -t NS dnsseed.machinenode.de` I just get `NXDOMAIN` as status and no namserver returned.

Is anyone familar with setting up a dnsseed and able to help?

Thanks and friendly regards

Nico

**EDIT:**

After switching my servers OS from CentOS 7 to Ubuntu 16.04 things started working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add or alter a DNS record you need to update the serial number in the zone data and take into account the TTL (time to live) which is used by clients as a cache refresh interval.

If you are using a hosting provider's web-based control-panel, it probably takes care of the serial number for you but it won't adjust the TTL in advance of the change. Therefore your change can take a while to propagate through third-party and client DNS caches.

NXDOMAIN means "no such domain" - so far as the nearest DNS server is concerned, it has a still-valid set of data for the parent zone and that does not contain the delegation you enquired about.

```
$ dig +nocmd +multiline +noall +answer machinenode.de
machinenode.de.         600 IN A 50.63.202.40

$ dig +nocmd +multiline +noall +answer dnsseed.machinenode.de
dnsseed.machinenode.de. 30 IN A 92.242.132.15
```

Those numbers 600 and 30 are the TTL values.

Comment: Okay thanks, however I've added those records few days ago (after registering the domain)...atleast the dnsseed. one

Comment: also, if I do `dig -t NS dnsseed.machinenode.de @ns01.machinenode.de` it works fine